# File system tracker

Tags: windows, filesystems

As everybody I have gigabytes of critical files storing on my NAS which is syncing with online storage.
But sync conflicts or just hard drive errors can break my solid storage system.

I'd like to find software which will remember my critical data folder/file structure to let me know if something has gone wrong.
Now I found just solutions that watch concrete folder and notify about any changes.
It's ok by, but I'm looking exactly for folder structure saver.

Comment: This isn't a solution but may be of interest. The `tree` command  `C:\>tree<ENTER>` will show and let you save folder structure `C:\>tree >c:\mydirectory\structure.txt` but doesn't monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If your external is NTFS, you can use Windows Backup and it will capture point in time versions of your folder and file structure. Much better than Dropbox or Bittorrent Sync when it comes to restoring entire folder structures or just knowing what your files looked like on a certain date.